# /bin/sh don't read .profile after update to mac os x 10.10

Tags: terminal, macos, command-line, macports

I have updated my mac os x to 10.10 and got a lot of problems with program compilations. It looks like that default /bin/sh are not reading .profile anymore. So, all scripts, which are dependent from environment variables don't works. Even make cannot perform compilations because it cannot find compiler executables in non-default paths. Some (but not all!) macports ports are broken now, I think because of this problem. Does anybody know, how to fix this?

Thanks in advance,
Pavel.

Comment: Do you mean /bin/sh or the shell that is used in Terminal which is probably /bin/bash ?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if something loaded a '.bash_profile', which would be read in preference to .profile.  If so, you can probably move it out of the way:

```
mv .bash_profile .saved_bash_profile
```

Comment: I have runed /bin/sh via dtruss to see, which files are accessed during startup, only history and inputrc are readed, .bash_profile is also ignored in yosemite